# How to pass json of 6800 characters in web service?

Tags: json, rest, web-services

I program in Java and i use jersey

i want to pass json composed of 6800 characters to my web service

initially I put it as a queryParam, but but it didn't work.
Then i change with HeaderParam but it does not work yet.
what should i do?

```
@Path("InsertSconti")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String InsertCustomer(@HeaderParam("token") String token,@QueryParam("customer") String customer)
{
```

http://localhost:8087/clayapi/restservices/InsertCustomer?customer= json(of 6800 characters)

it gives me error 400 Bad Request

Comment: Use `POST` request instead of `GET`?

Comment: What does _didn't work_ mean?

Comment: but it doesn't work

Comment: it gives me error 400 bad request

Comment: What framework are you using? What language are you programming in? Please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: i update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `Requestparam`

I used it in this way

```
@RestController
    public class OutlookController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/api", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK) 
         public String pushNotification(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "code") String code) {
           System.out.println("yes done");
            System.out.println(code);
                        return "sai";
        }
}

curl -X POST -d {code:"hhhhh"} http://localhost:8080/api
```

Give customer json in above curl after "-d".
If you use postman or soap UI to test your service give json in request body.

This will allow you to give more than 6800 chars.